# Obtaining model's name through rails console gives different results

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I was just wondering if anyone could help.

I'm trying to obtain a model's name through rails console and it is giving me different results.

First I do:

```
Department.first.name
```

and the result is:

```
Department Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "departments".* FROM "departments"  ORDER BY "departments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> "Operations"
```

then I do:

```
ops = Department.where(name: "Operations")
```

and the result is:

```
=> ActiveRecord::Relation #[Department id: 1, name: "Operations", created_at: "2017-10-22 00:40:51", updated_at: "2017-10-22 00:40:51"]>
```

but then if I am trying to get:

```
ops.name
```

the result is:

```
=> "Department"
```

This confuses me and leads to association issues. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you use `where` this gives you an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and as you can see, they can be a single or multiple objects depending on what's on your database, but you must iterate them to give the specific attribute on each of them.

In the case you use `Model.first`, it gives you the specific record, that's why you can access "directly" to this object's attribute.

If what you want is to get the name attribute of each of your departments then you can use `pluck`, like:

```
Department.where(condition).pluck(attributes)
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Even if `ops` has just one result is not a single `Department` but an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so

`ops.name` is giving you the model name (the class name).

You need to get the first one

```
ops.first.name
```

Comment: my pleasure sir :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ops = Department.where(name: "Operations")
```

returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. not a `Department` object (unless you state a cosntraint (first, last etc.)). You've defined a `name` property for `Department` class which returns the `name` field from database. Not for ActiveRecord::Relation; and `name` has a different meaning there. It returns relation/class's name.